# Why is this sporadically throwing a null reference error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

Okay, this code sporadically throws a null reference error because the return ((AVMain)this.Page).Model isn't returning anything.  I have not been able to make this error recur, even with the same ID value that fails for other people.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    protected AVModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            return ((AVMain)this.Page).Model;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SessionData.IsAudit.HasValue && SessionData.IsAudit.Value == true)
        {
            cbFlagAudit.Visible = false;
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cbFlagAudit.Checked = this.Model.FlagForAudit.HasValue ? this.Model.FlagForAudit.Value : false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set a conditional breakpoint and traverse back the stack.

Comment: @null That's only useful if the debugger is running on the live server, which it almost certainly won't be. At least the way I'm reading the question, users are getting error messages, but the OP is unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Top tip: you can replace that double test of `SessionData.IsAudit` with `if (SessionData.IsAudit == true)`. If it's null, that returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your advice, but the error was actually being generated due to a permissions error in the database.  It was causing a stored procedure to fail and not return the data needed to populate the object, hence it was null.  The initial developers did not put error trapping in this project, so something that should taken no time to find, took a few days.  ALWAYS trap your errors!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by adding some null-reference checks throughout the logic.  That should prevent a `NullReferenceException` from being thrown.

How's this?

```
protected AVModel Model
{
    get
    {
        if(this.Page is AVMain)
        { 
            var page = this.Page as AVMain;
            return page.Model;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SessionData.IsAudit.HasValue && SessionData.IsAudit.Value == true)
    {
        cbFlagAudit.Visible = false;
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var model = this.Model;
        Boolean? value = null;
        if(model != null)
        {
            value = model.FlagForAudit;
        }
        cbFlagAudit.Checked = (value.HasValue && value.Value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, it is working to catch if the model is null, but I still can't figure out why page.Model isn't being created.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: The `this.Page` will return `null` (which would cause your issue) when it is called from inside a templated control, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026651/asp-net-page-object-null-when-invoking-it-from-within-templated-control).  An answer on that question (though not accepted) might be worth trying.  Swap the line that says `var page = this.Page as AVMain;` with `var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;`.  You'll also need to change the line above it to also check if the type of that object is correct.